# headerStyle in Dynamic Columns primereact datatable

Tags: primereact

I'm using dynamic columns in **PrimeReact** **Datatable** component:

```
const columns = [
  {
    field: 'code',
    header: 'Code',
    body: bodyTemplate,
    headerStyle: {{minWidth: '15rem'}},
    sortable: 'sortable',
  },
  ...
]
```

I defined **bodyTemplate** as:

```
const bodyTemplate = (rowData) => {
  return (
    <>
      <span className='p-column-title'>Code</span>
      {rowData.code}
    </>
  )
}
```

But I don't know how to define **headerStyle**. Is it possible and how can I do that in dynamic columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it as follow:

change

> `headerStyle: {{minWidth: '15rem'}}`

to

> `headerStyle: {minWidth: '15rem'}`

in columns array as:

```
const columns = [
  {
    field: 'code',
    header: 'Code',
    body: bodyTemplate,
    headerStyle: {minWidth: '15rem'},
    sortable: 'sortable',
  },
  ...
]
```

and then in Datatable map columns define `headerStyle={col.headerStyle}` as:

```
{columns.map((col) => (
  <Column
    field={col.field}
    header={col.header}
    body={col.body}
    sortable={col.sortable}
    headerStyle={col.headerStyle}
  />
))}
```